# Does reverse_iterator inherit from iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Let it be `std::list::iterator` and `std::list::reverse_iterator`. Is reverse one derived from forward? And if not then why there're not reverse equivalents for member functions of `list`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there's no inheritance relation between them. What kind of reverse operations where you expecting?

Comment: @larsmans I expect possibility of doing `my_list.erase(reverse_i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Let it be std::list::iterator and std::list::reverse_iterator. Is reverse one derived from forward?

Not necessarily, they may (and probably are in most implementations) different types. Iterators are copied around all the time, and this inheritance would cause slicing. Plus, all operations on `iterator` should be `virtual` to avoid inconsistencies, which would be inefficient. Thinking about it, it would make sense for the standard to even forbid inheritance as a possible implementation (and maybe it does, indirectly).

**Update:** The standard provides a definition for `std::reverse_iterator` class template, and mandates that `std::list::reverse_iterator` is a specialization of such template. Inheritance is not a possible implementation.

> And if not then why there're not reverse equivalents for member functions of list?

Because you can call `base()` on a `reverse_iterator` to get the underlying regular `iterator`. The fundamental relation between a `reverse_iterator` and its corresponding `iterator` `i` is that `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1).`

Comment: 1. I can get base iterator, but it's shifted and I shall do `--i.base()` or somethink like this. 
2. What do you mean when you say "inheritance would cause slicing". What is slicing?

Comment: @tonytony: 1. Indeed, the fundamental relation is `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`. You shouldn't do `--i.base()` because that _(may?)_ changes the `reverse_iterator` position as well, but you can do `i.base() - 1` since its a bidirectional iterator. 2. Its what happens when you mix inheritance with value semantics, search for it there is ton of information available.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but `i.base() - 1` is not legal for anything but random access iterators, so you _can't_ do that for `std::list<>` iterators (C++11 §24.2.6-7).

Comment: @ildjarn: Oh boy I'm ashamed! So what's the alternative here? Copy the result from `base()` and decrement it?

Comment: @K-ballo : Yep, making a copy of the iterator then prefix-decrementing it is the correct approach. Iterators are universally supposed to be cheap to copy for exactly this reason.

Comment: @ildjarn: Which makes it impossible to do it without an auxiliary iterator, unless using something like `boost::prior` :(

Comment: @ildjarn: Not that I recommend doing it, but would something like `(++iter)--` work?

Comment: I thought you were trying to avoid modifying the iterator directly?

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm trying to get the adjusted base iterator (a copy) without an auxiliary variable. But I don't think it can be done...

Comment: You can safely modify the result of `base()`, as it returns a copy. Direct access to the underlying iterator is by a protrcted data member `current`

Answer (score 1):

In GNU's implementation of the C++ standard library, there's a has-a relationship between a reverse_iterator and an iterator.  (I haven't ever looked through the MSVC++ or llvm implementations, but I would imagine that they're the same.)

Basically, the reverse_iterator takes in an iterator and has a thin wrapper so that ++ aliases to -- and -- aliases to ++.  Basically all of the operations are wrappers around the underlying non-reverse iterator.

> And if not then why there're not reverse equivalents for member functions of list?

`std::list` does have a [reverse iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin).